# Apache solr-5.3.1 SolrCore Collection Detached issue on server restart

Tags: java, apache, solr5

I am using the latest version of Bitnami Apache solr and the issue that I am facing is after adding a SolrCore every time services or server got restart the attached SolrCore collection got detached, and the interface shows like there was never been any SolrCore attached before.

But the strange thing is when I am attaching the SolrCore again the solr interface shows a error message "another core is already defined there" and once I refresh the page its like nothing happen everything fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h9as.png)

This mean core exist on the back end but some reference is removed because of the services restart.

So I need to know why this happening? why core is getting detached after the services restarted? And how can I fix this issue?

Reference link of a solr version I am using:
https://bitnami.com/stack/solr/installer

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is a SoftReference linked inside a Service, which is lost, causing these trouble.

I think you should look for a UnitedService which starts and stop together, keeping an united work in the same Context.

You could start/stop all your webserver and Solr instances together, at the same time,  with a batch script. And you can look at how the SoftReferences are working inside Solr manual and which usual problems they are facing with.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually this kind of issue never happen in previous versions of solr, So I am not so familiar with back end services and I did not know about the "SoftReferences". I can use the batch file but I am not able to find any command which will attached the available cores at the back end. can you provide me links where I can find something link that?